# Distribution where the variance diverges for some parameter values but not others

Tags: distributions, variance, moments

I'm wondering whether there's a standard / nice / tractable family of distributions where the variance is defined for some parameter values but not others, while the mean stays finite.

I'm imagining a parameter that controls the variance, such that there's a critical value at which the variance goes to infinity and is undefined above the critical value.

It would be ideal if the support was the non-negative reals for all parameter values, with the pdf decreasing monotonically even in the case where the variance is undefined.

Comment: $t$ distribution? You can wreck the mean, too, but just demand that the parameter exceeds $1$.

Comment: Another example is the Pareto, for a range of parameter values.

Comment: Ah yes, good. These both work, and the Pareto might end up fitting my needs fairly well. (I didn't say it in the question, but it's nice if it has non-negative support. It would be even nicer if the support was exactly the non-negative reals.)

Comment: These could be posted as answers though. The question is trivial if you happen to know the relevant examples, but that's no reason to disregard the usual Stack Exchange "don't put answers in the comments" advice.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example would be the [T-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with degrees-of-freedom no less than two.  If you want the mean to be non-trivial then you could use a shifted T-distribution with a mean parameter.  If you want you could take the family of shifted T-distributions with degrees-of-freedom no less than two and then reparameterise it with a mean parameter $\mu$ and variance parameter $\sigma^2$.  This gives the density function:

$$\text{St}(x | \mu, \sigma^2)
= \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2-1}{2 \sigma^2 \pi}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma \big( \tfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2-1} + \tfrac{1}{2} \big)}{\Gamma \big( \tfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2-1} \big)} \cdot \Bigg( 1 + \frac{\sigma^2-1}{2\sigma^2} \cdot (x-\mu)^2 \Bigg)^{- \tfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2-1} - \tfrac{1}{2}},$$

where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ is the **mean parameter** and $\sigma^2 \in [1, \infty]$ is the **variance parameter**.